# How do I align the image and text so it does not wrap?

Tags: html, css

I want to show an image with text next to the image. 3 images in a row. The following code example will wrap the text but I need it all to fit the width of the container.

I have seen that this can be achieved using a unordered list as well but I have not been able to figure that out either.

```
.banner-row {
  display: flex;
}
.banner-column {
  flex: 33.33%;
  padding: 15px;
}
.banner-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center
}

banner-img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height:100%;
}

.banner-text {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

I then have the html code as follows:

```
<div class="banner-row">
  <div class="banner-column">
    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0778/0778/0187/files/reduces-headaches-yellow.png" alt="Snow" style="width:33%"><div>Reduces Headaches</div>
  </div>
  <div class="banner-column">
    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0778/0778/0187/files/relieves-neck-pain-yellow.png" alt="Forest" style="width:33%"><div>Relieves Neck Pain</div>
  </div>
  <div class="banner-column">
    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0778/0778/0187/files/wake-up-refreshed-yello.png" alt="Mountains" style="width:33%"><div>Improves Sleep</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Image shows the text wrapping]

Answer (score 0):

Just add display: flex in banner-column it should work

```
.banner-column {
  flex: 33.33%;
  padding: 15px;
  display: flex;
}
```

to make them align center

```
    .banner-column {
          flex: 33.33%;
          padding: 15px;
          display: flex;
align-items: center;
        }
```

Comment: That worked thanks man. Simple when you know how :) The text is not centered to the image. How would I do that?

Comment: In fact, would it be possible if on mobile to show the text centered, underneath the image and on a larger screen, next to the image? The images have got all skewed now.

Answer (score 0):

```
.banner-column {
  flex: 33.33%;
  display : flex;
  justify-content : center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

Comment: This answer was reviewed in the [Low Quality Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality). Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are **not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / **better** than existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/35010415)

Comment: Thank you for all the help. It's looking great on desktop but on mobile, it would be better if the text showed below the image. Do I do this in the html or css? Again, appreciate all the help.

Comment: yeah use media query for responsive design

Answer (score 0):

Your banner text div elements had no classes in them. I added some code to style the body just to make it easier to see. I hope this code produces the results you want.

```
/*Copy paste in .html file and run it.*/
<style>
    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        background: rgb(10, 2, 20);
        color: white;
        display: grid;
        justify-content: center; /*remove if you don't want a centered layout*/
        
    }

    .banner-row {
        display: flex;
       
    }
    .banner-column {
        display: flex;
        padding: 15px;
        
    }
    .banner-container {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center
    }

    .banner-img {
        width: 33%;
    }

    .banner-text {
        font-size: 20px;
        padding-left: 20px;
    }
    /* Clear floats after the columns */
    .row:after {
        content: "";
        display: table;
        clear: both;
    }
</style>




<div class="banner-row">
    <div class="banner-column">
      <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0778/0778/0187/files/reduces-headaches-yellow.png" alt="Snow" class="banner-img"/>
      <div class="banner-text">Reduces Headaches</div>
    </div>
    <div class="banner-column">
      <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0778/0778/0187/files/relieves-neck-pain-yellow.png" alt="Forest" class="banner-img" />
      <div class="banner-text">Relieves Neck Pain</div>
    </div>
    <div class="banner-column">
      <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0778/0778/0187/files/wake-up-refreshed-yello.png" alt="Mountains" class="banner-img" />
      <div class="banner-text">Improves Sleep</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```